# Log4j in Elasticsearch Prerequisites

Tags: java, elasticsearch, azure-devops, log4j

currently i have elasticsearch **v6.2** installed as a Prerequisites in my Azure DevOps environment, the version of the Log4j running is **2.9.1**:

```
 .\Search\ElasticSearch\elasticsearchv6.2\lib\log4j-1.2-api-2.9.1.jar
 .\Search\ElasticSearch\elasticsearchv6.2\lib\log4j-api-2.9.1.jar
 .\Search\ElasticSearch\elasticsearchv6.2\lib\log4j-core-2.9.1.jar
```

As i understand the version of the log4j contains the security vulnerability so i have deactivated the service in the environment to be safe.

So my question is should i update **log4j** only and if so which one from the listed above?

Can I update only log4j or do I have to update elasticsearch as a whole?

I haven't found any info online about updating elasticsearch as a prerequisites for Azure DevOps. How can I do that?

Comment: I believe there is a discussion here : https://discuss.elastic.co/t/mitigation-for-log4j2-vulnerability/291938 that could help

Comment: Also this blog post: https://xeraa.net/blog/2021_mitigate-log4j2-log4shell-elasticsearch/

Comment: You're running unsupported version of Elasticsearch so it's a good idea to upgrade, see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/azure-devops-and-azure-devops-server-and-the-log4j-vulnerability/

Comment: @ilvar Thank you sir, that is exactly what i was looking for.